# dataframe treating my first column as an index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am querying some data from a SQL table into a dataframe using the read_sql_query method.

It works however there is one thing I don't quite understand.

So my SQL query selects 3 columns, the first is date (all unique), the second some text and third a float.

When I run df.dtypes I get the following output,

```
 City         object
 Population   float64
```

Why has it ignore my date column? It has made it the index for the dataframe. What if I don't want this behaviour, is there anyway to stop this?

**Update**

Below are the paramters I pass to the function.

```
df = pd.read_sql_query(query, cnxn)
```

When I run df.Head(3) the output is like,

```
               City     Population

  Date
  2018-01-01   Paris    4
  2018-01-02   NY       6
  2018-01-03   London   5
```

Comment: Can you show the parameters you are passing to `read_sql_query`? It shouldn't set a column to the index unless you set `index_col`.

Comment: what is the output of df.head(3)? Check if it has converted to an index. Ideally, it converts when you set the parse_dates attribute in your call.

Comment: @mfitzp sure, I have updated my post

Comment: @TheRoy it seems to me that is has been converted to an index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You start with this where you have a DateIndex

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'City': ['Paris', 'NY', 'London'],
    'Population': [4, 6, 5],
    'Date': pd.date_range('2018-01-01', '2018-01-03')
})
df = df.set_index('Date')

>>> df
            City    Population
Date        
2018-01-01  Paris   4
2018-01-02  NY      6
2018-01-03  London  5
```

Fortunately, it's as simple as calling `reset_index()`.

```py
>>> df.reset_index()

    Date        City    Population
0   2018-01-01  Paris   4
1   2018-01-02  NY      6
2   2018-01-03  London  5
```